# what is $\lim_{k \to 0}\frac{(k+1)A-3kA+2A^3}{(k-A^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ where $A=-\sqrt{2} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}$

Tags: calculus, limits, gamma-function

let $k>0$ and define
$$A=-\sqrt{2} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}$$

and

$$\gamma(k)=\frac{(k+1)A-3kA+2A^3}{(k-A^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$
Where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) function.

What is

$$\lim_{k \to 0^{+}} \gamma(k)?$$

**First try**

So

$$\gamma(k)=\frac{A-2kA+2A^3}{(k-A^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{A^{3}}{A^{3}}
\frac{1/A^2-2k/A^2+2}{(k/A^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{1/A^2-2k/A^2+2}{(k/A^2-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

But I  stuck in $\lim_{k \to 0}k/A^2$?

Since $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}$ so $A\sim -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}$ so

$$\gamma(k)=\frac{\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2})}{2\pi}-2k\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2})}{2\pi}+2}{(k\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2})}{2\pi}-1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=
\frac{
\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2})(1-2k)+4\pi}{2\pi}
}{
\frac{
(k\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2}) -2\pi)^{3/2}
}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}
}
$$

$$=\sqrt(2\pi)\frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2})(1-2k)+4\pi}{(k\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2}) -2\pi)^{3/2}}$$

By using $\Gamma(z)=\frac1z - \gamma + o(1)$ (mentioned by @Brian Tung)

$$\Gamma^2(\frac{k}{2})=(\frac{2}{k} - \gamma + o(1))^2
=\frac{4}{k^2}+\gamma^2+o^2(1)-2\gamma \frac{2}{k} +2\frac{2}{k}o(1)-2\gamma o(1) $$

**Second try**

By knowing that  $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$  [(4.1 The complement formula)][2]

$$A\sim -\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})} =-\sqrt{2\pi} \frac{\Gamma(1-\frac{k}{2})\sin(\pi \frac{k}{2})}{\pi} \sim -\sqrt{2\pi} \frac{\sin(\pi \frac{k}{2})}{\pi}=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \sin (\frac{k\pi}{2}) $$

so by Taylor expansion
$$A\sim -\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left\{ (\frac{k\pi}{2}) -\frac{(\frac{k\pi}{2})^3}{3!} \right\} $$ and so

$$\gamma(k)=\frac{(1-2k)A+2A^3}{(k-A^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=
\frac{(1-2k)\left(
-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left\{ (\frac{k\pi}{2}) -\frac{(\frac{k\pi}{2})^3}{3!} \right\}
\right)+2
\left(
-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left\{ (\frac{k\pi}{2}) -\frac{(\frac{k\pi}{2})^3}{3!} \right\}
\right)^3}{\left(k-
\left(
-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \left\{ (\frac{k\pi}{2}) -\frac{(\frac{k\pi}{2})^3}{3!} \right\}
\right)^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$

Comment: Can you make anything of the fact that $\Gamma(z) = \frac1z - \gamma + o(1)$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)?

Comment: Apparently, $\gamma (k) \sim   - \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2k}}} $ as $k\to 0+$.

Comment: @Gary Why $\gamma (k) \sim  - \frac{{1.253 \ldots }}{{\sqrt k }}$?

Comment: @Brian Tung, I am working on it. But I stuck in $\Gamma^2(z)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composing Taylor series, we have
$$A=-\sqrt{2}\, \frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}$$
$$A=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k^2 \log (2)+O\left(k^3\right)$$
$$A^2=\frac{\pi  k^2}{2}-\pi  k^3 \log (2)+O\left(k^4\right)$$
$$A^3=-\frac{\pi ^{3/2} k^3}{2 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{3 \pi ^{3/2} k^4 \log (2)}{2
   \sqrt{2}}+O\left(k^5\right)$$

So, (strangely written for me),
$$(k+1)A-3kA+2A^3=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k^2 (2+\log (2))+O\left(k^3\right)$$
$$\left(k-A^2\right)^{3/2}=k^{3/2}-\frac{3}{4} \pi  k^{5/2}+\frac{1}{2} k^{7/2} \left(\frac{3 \pi ^2}{16}+3
   \pi  \log (2)\right)+O\left(k^{9/2}\right)$$ Now, long division
$$\gamma(k)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 k}}\left(1+\frac{1}{4} k (-8+3 \pi -\log (16))+O\left(k^2\right)\right)\sim -\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 k}}\to -\infty$$

Comment: Could you explain how you get $A=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k^2 \log (2)+O\left(k^3\right)$?.

Comment: @M.M. Truncated series expansion of the gamma function around $k=0$

Comment: I got $A=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} k-\frac{1}{2}(\gamma \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}) k^2 +O\left(k^3\right)$ from
 https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=f9476968629e1163bd4a3ba839d60925&title=Taylor%20Series&theme=blue&i0=-sqrt(2pi)%2Fgamma(k%2F2)&i1=k&i2=0&i3=1&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1 ?!!!

Comment: @M.M. Why you entered is not the expression of $A$

Comment: @M.M https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=f9476968629e1163bd4a3ba839d60925&title=Taylor%20Series&theme=blue&i0=-sqrt(2pi)%2Fgamma(k%2F2)&i1=k&i2=0&i3=1&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1  and simplify to get my answer

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Why $-\frac{1}{2}\gamma$ is equal to $\log(2)$. Am i wrong something( According to  https://www.wolframalpha.com/widget/widgetPopup.jsp?p=v&id=f9476968629e1163bd4a3ba839d60925&title=Taylor%20Series&theme=blue&i0=-sqrt(2pi)%2Fgamma(k%2F2)&i1=k&i2=0&i3=1&podSelect=&showAssumptions=1&showWarnings=1 and simplify to get my answer)

Comment: Can you refer to a link for $A$, $A^2$ and $A^3$. It can help me to understand the solution.

Comment: How you conclude $\gamma(k)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 k}}\left(1+\frac{1}{4} k (-8+3 \pi -\log (16))+O\left(k^2\right)\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

By using the expansion of $\gamma(k)$ we have:
$$\gamma(k)=-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{k} \left(-3 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2}-2 \gamma  \sqrt{2 \pi }+8 \sqrt{2 \pi }-2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+O\left(k^{3/2}\right)$$ therefore $\gamma(k)\to -\infty$ as $k\to 0^+$